# Pagination Url parsing issue

Tags: php, pdo, pagination

I have a pagination script that seems fairly well used and I converted it to PDO and I am having trouble with parsing of two variables.

The url for the page is

current-events.php?event_id=62

When I go to page 2, the url reads

urrent-events.php?page=2

However it still displays the results for page 1, I am missing the event_id

The issue seems to be I am not able to call the event_id and the pages.

Can anyone see the error of my ways?

Thank you

Gary

```
                <?php 
            require_once("pdoconnect.inc.php");
            $event_id = $_GET['event_id'];
            ?>

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                $tbl_name="victims";        //your table name
                // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
                $adjacents = 3;

                /* 
                   First get total number of rows in data table. 
                   If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
                */
                $query = "SELECT event_id  FROM $tbl_name WHERE event_id = '$event_id' ";

                $q = $conn->prepare($query);
                $q->execute();
                $total_pages = $q->rowCount();
                echo $total_pages;

                //$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
                //$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

              //?event_id=$event_id
                $targetpage = "current-events.php";     //your file name  (the name of this file)
                                    //how many items to show per page
                            $limit = 10;                

              $page = $_GET['page'];




                if($page) 
                    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
                else
                    $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

                /* Get data. */
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE event_id = '$_GET[event_id]' ORDER BY lname ASC LIMIT $start, $limit ";
                    $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    $result->execute();
                //$result = mysql_query($sql);

                /* Setup page vars for display. */
                if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
                $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
                $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
                $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
                $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

                /* 
                    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
                    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
                */
                $pagination = "";
                if($lastpage > 1)
                {   
                    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
                    //previous button
                    if ($page > 1) 
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">� previous</a>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">� previous</span>"; 

                    //pages 
                    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
                    {   
                        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                        {
                            if ($counter == $page)
                                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                            else
                                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                        }
                    }
                    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
                    {
                        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
                        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
                        {
                            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                            {
                                if ($counter == $page)
                                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                                else
                                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                            }
                            $pagination.= "...";
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
                        }
                        //in middle; hide some front and some back
                        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                        {
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\"> 1 </a>";
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\"> 2 </a>";
                            $pagination.= "...";
                            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                            {
                                if ($counter == $page)
                                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                                else
                                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                            }
                            $pagination.= "...";
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
                        }
                        //close to end; only hide early pages
                        else
                        {
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\"> 1 </a>";
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\"> 2 </a>";
                            $pagination.= "...";
                            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                            {
                                if ($counter == $page)
                                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                                else
                                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    //next button
                    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\"> next  � </a>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\"> next � </span>";
                    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
                }

            ?>
            <table>
```

Comment: Please note: you are still vulnerable to **sql injection**. Using pdo doesn't magically make you safe from injections. Learn how to make proper prepared query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `$event_id` in the first `$query` is an empty variable.
You can solve the problem with something like:

```
$event_id = $_GET['event_id'];
```

(then you have to change the second query and put `$event_id` instead of `$_GET[event_id]`)

But be aware of **SQL INJECTION** as @itachi said!

---

I think you lose a parameter when you click on a pagination link, you must add `event_id` to the urls.
The pagination code is long, but you can solve the problem by searching for `$targetpage?page` and replacing it with `$targetpage?event_id=$event_id&page`

Comment: Guglielmo - Thank you for your reply.  It was not included in my sample code, however I have $event_id = $_GET['event_id']; in the file,  I read the page you referenced from php.net & they recommend using the prepare() vs the quote() " If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are strongly recommended to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL statements with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote() to interpolate user input into an SQL statement. Prepared statements with bound parameters are not only more portable, more convenient, immune to SQL injection, "

Comment: @Gary Sorry, I've removed the link (and I've never used quote, but thanks). Can you post the complete code?

Comment: I have edited the code above, most if not all is extraneous html/css.  Thank you for your help. Gary

Comment: @Gary ok, by _complete code_ I meant the _complete PHP code_. Maybe you can re-edit your question removing HTML to make it more readable. By the way I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it.  I went up and edited out the extra code for people that may come across this post in the future. Thank you for your help. Gary